# Include in header or cpp - what is preferred in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, header, include

When I write a C++ class I write includes in header only is specific cases. I prefer forward declaration and I believe that is best practice in C++. But Qt classes often have so many fields that are standard Qt classes that writing them all in forward declaration seems like not a very good idea. Is there some preferred way? Qt has huge documentation, so I think that it has answer to my question, but I just started reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt, for this purpose, is just a C++ library. You can certainly continue to write forward declarations. If your classes become bloated, this may indicate that you're mixing UI (presentation) and data/logic code in one class. A cleaner separation of responsibilities may enable you to replace a few complex classes with a larger number of simpler classes.

Answer (score 5):

My rule is for a header file to include only those files that define functionality that is used by the header file in question.

Suppose you have pointers and references to some class `Foo` in a header but the header never pokes into or instantiates one those objects. In this case, you don't need the definition of the class. All you need is a forward declaration.

On the other hand, a forward declaration does not suffice if you poke into an object of type `Foo`, or if you have a data member or variable of type `Foo`. Now you do need the full definition, so now it is time to `#include` the header file that defines class `Foo`. (Alternatively, if the use is in an inline function definition, you may want to rethink that inlining and put the implementation in a separate source file.)

Comment: Forward declarations are for header files. Header files should compile on there own. it is item 34 in Scott Myers Effective C++ (my copy looks like it has been savaged by the coffee monster!). `#include` should be the last resort.

Comment: I agree completely. Well, almost completely. Replace "should" with "must": Header files *must* compile on their own. I should (must!) be able to add a `#include "foo.h"` to a do-nothing test program (e.g. `int main() { return 0; }` ) and have that program still compile and run.

Comment: I also agree with preferring forward declarations over inclusion. Inclusion obviously is needed when a header defines a class that contains a data member of some non-primitive, non-pointer type that isn't defined in the header at hand. Otherwise, I view the need to include a header in a header as a bit suspect.

Comment: Their is me again trying to sweet the bitter pill. I should have wrote *must*

Answer (score 2):

A header file just says "what we can do". The `cpp` file says "We can do it this way and that is our intention".

Comment: Inline function definitions in a header also say "we can do it this way and that is our intention".

Comment: @DavidHammen - Always the exception to prove the rule. But those functions tend to be (or should be) rather limited in scope.

Answer (score 1):

This is for JvO - You say

*It is always a trade-off; forward declarations force you to:
a) only use pointers to your forwarded class in other header files;
b) include the header file in each and every .cc/.cpp file that uses the class.*

These are valid:

```
class Ditto;

Ditto letsHaveANewOne();
void useIt(Ditto X);
```

So where are the pointers?

Forward declarations avoid the need to have dependencies. This is good because it enables the compiler to offload some of the hassle to the linker. Also consider lots of code that has that header file and has to open files, parse them, etc. for a class declaration. You save time in the long run.

*Forward declarations are IMO only useful if
c) your code is in a state of flux, and you want to avoid massive recompiles;
d) your class declarations are huge.*

See above - it is also known as decoupling. Try it - will save time in the long run.

Comment: This code may be valid, but you can't use Ditto as a *member* variable in another class unless you use pointers. I do use forward declarations, and I'm just pointing out some of the problems I have encountered in practice. It may save time, but I do not think the advantages always outweigh the disadvantages.

Comment: @JvO - The header file tells what can be done. When a .cpp file requires a `Ditto` object **YOU** include it into that file i.e. not all .cpp files that include that header file. That means the .cpp file includes those files that it needs. Other .cpp files do not have to do this if they are not interested.

Comment: @JvO - Of course if they are a member variable they should be `#included`. But not as a matter of course. It is prudent to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a trade-off; forward declarations force you to:
a) only use pointers to your forwarded class in other header files;
b) include the header file in each and every .cc/.cpp file that uses the class.

Both are a bit cumbersome sometimes; specifically with a) you can't use or return a reference to your forwarded declared class, and point b) is annoying to type and generates long lists of #includes in your c++ file.

Forward declarations are IMO only useful if
c) your code is in a state of flux, and you want to avoid massive recompiles;
d) your class declarations are *huge*.

Point c) does not apply to Qt (assuming you don't update the library every day). d) does apply, but that can be alleviated by using precompiled header files if your compiler supports it.

Qt (4.7 at least) does not have bundled forward declarations, except for containers (list, set, map, etc) in QtContainerFwd. If you find yourself typing the same list of forward declarations over and over again you may want to consider creating your own header file with these declarations.